# R: combine several apply() function in a pipe

Tags: r

I'm working with the universal dataset 'palmerpenguins'. In particular, I wanto to calculate the minimum and maximum of all numeric columns. I'm doing it with pipe functions.

```
install.packages("palmerpenguins")
library(palmerpenguins)

penguins_raw %>%
      select_if(is.numeric) %>%
      apply(2, min, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
      apply(2, max, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
      as.data.frame() %>%
      rownames_to_column(var = 'col')
```

But I get this error:

**Error in apply(., 2, max, na.rm = TRUE) : dim(X) must have a positive length**

My doubt is: Is it possible to combine 2 apply() in the same pipeline ? How can I do this ? Thankyou :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you break this down step by step it will be easier to understand. The output after getting minimum value in each column is :

```
library(dplyr)
library(palmerpenguins)

penguins_raw %>%
  select_if(is.numeric) %>%
  apply(2, min, na.rm = TRUE)

# Sample Number  Culmen Length (mm)   Culmen Depth (mm) Flipper Length (mm) 
#          1.00               32.10               13.10              172.00 

#      Body Mass (g)   Delta 15 N (o/oo)   Delta 13 C (o/oo) 
#            2700.00                7.63              -27.02
```

Now to this output you are applying the function `apply(2, max, na.rm = TRUE)` which is not what you want because you want to get `max` for each column from `penguins_raw` dataset and not from the above output.

---

If you are using pipes and `dplyr` function there are dedicated functions to perform such calculation.  In this case you can use `across`.

```
penguins_raw %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), list(min = ~min(., na.rm = TRUE), 
                                           max = ~max(., na.rm = TRUE))))
```

Or if you are on older version of `dplyr` use `summarise_if` as :

```
penguins_raw %>%
  summarise_if(is.numeric, list(min = ~min(., na.rm = TRUE), 
                                           max = ~max(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

---

To get data into 3-column format we can use `pivot_longer`.

```
penguins_raw %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), list(min = ~min(., na.rm = TRUE), 
                                           max = ~max(., na.rm = TRUE)))) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
               names_to = c('name', '.value'), 
               names_sep = '_')

#  name                    min    max
#  <chr>                 <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 Sample Number          1     152  
#2 Culmen Length (mm)    32.1    59.6
#3 Culmen Depth (mm)     13.1    21.5
#4 Flipper Length (mm)  172     231  
#5 Body Mass (g)       2700    6300  
#6 Delta 15 N (o/oo)      7.63   10.0
#7 Delta 13 C (o/oo)    -27.0   -23.8
```

Comment: Thankyou so much ! But if I want to create from it a dataframe with 3 columns ? Like, the first one indicates the columns that the dataframe has, the second one the maximum value of them and the third one the minimum value, how can separate it ?

Comment: @EduardoCabria We can use `pivot_longer` to get data in that format. See updated answer.